# How to get/set internal state of a CFB_Mode Encryption Object?

Tags: c++, crypto++

Is it possible to create a new `Encryption` object that has the same internal state as a previously created `Encryption` object (I need this, to only keep the IV between function calls, and not the whole object)?

I thought it should be possible with the function `GetNextIV` but I didn't get the right result. In the following example the string `This is the text` gets encoded and the correct encoded text is:

```
94-41-d2-d4-06-05-f6-cd-d0-25-d6-f4-f6-52-55-7b-7c-
```

But I get:

```
94-a8-a9-b3-e0-a9-b3-e0-b4-a8-a5-e0-b4-a5-b8-b4-c0-
```

As you can see only the first byte (`94`) is encoded right. You can try it with following code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <crypto++/modes.h>
#include <crypto++/aes.h>
#include <crypto++/osrng.h>

using namespace CryptoPP;

void printHex(const byte in) {
    std::cout << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << std::hex << (int)in << "-";
}

int main() {

    // Generate a random key and IV
    AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
    SecByteBlock key(0x00, AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
    rnd.GenerateBlock(key, key.size());
    byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, AES::BLOCKSIZE);

    // Encrypt byte by byte
    // this results in the correct encrypted text
    byte text[] = "This is the text";
    int msgLen = sizeof(text);
    CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption cfbEncB(key, key.size(), iv);
    for (byte* beg = &text[0]; beg != &text[msgLen]; ++beg) {
        printHex(cfbEncB.ProcessByte(*beg));
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

    // Encrypt byte by byte only keeping IV for each iteration
    // This is not the expected output, how to get it right?
    byte nextiv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    std::copy(&iv[0], &iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE], &nextiv[0]);
    for (byte* beg = &text[0]; beg != &text[msgLen]; ++beg) {
        CFB_Mode<AES>::Encryption cfbEncC(key, key.size(), nextiv);
        printHex(cfbEncC.ProcessByte(*beg));
        cfbEncC.GetNextIV(nextiv);
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I thought it should be possible with the function `GetNextIV` but I didn't get the right result...

Sadly, NO. Here's the comments on `GetNextIV` from `cryptlib.h`:

```
//! get a secure IV for the next message
/*! This method should be called after you finish encrypting one message and are ready to start the next one.
    After calling it, you must call SetKey() or Resynchronize() before using this object again. 
    This method is not implemented on decryption objects. */
virtual void GetNextIV(RandomNumberGenerator &rng, byte *IV);
```

So `GetNextIV` is used to get IVs that meet the cipher's IV requirements for distinct messages, and not the internal state for the current message.

The second clue it does not reveal internal state is the PRNG parameter. If you use the `NullRNG()`, then it should throw an exception. Internal state should not be randomized :)

---

> How to ***get*** internal state of a CFB_Mode Encryption Object?

I *think* the internal state you are looking for is in `m_register` and `m_temp`. They are protected and lack accessors, so you will need to modify the library.

From `modes.h`:

```
class CRYPTOPP_DLL CRYPTOPP_NO_VTABLE CFB_ModePolicy : public ModePolicyCommonTemplate<CFB_CipherAbstractPolicy>
{
public:
    IV_Requirement IVRequirement() const {return RANDOM_IV;}
    static const char * CRYPTOPP_API StaticAlgorithmName() {return "CFB";}

protected:
    unsigned int GetBytesPerIteration() const {return m_feedbackSize;}
    byte * GetRegisterBegin() {return m_register + BlockSize() - m_feedbackSize;}
    bool CanIterate() const {return m_feedbackSize == BlockSize();}
    void Iterate(byte *output, const byte *input, CipherDir dir, size_t iterationCount);
    void TransformRegister();
    void CipherResynchronize(const byte *iv, size_t length);
    void SetFeedbackSize(unsigned int feedbackSize);
    void ResizeBuffers();

    SecByteBlock m_temp;
    unsigned int m_feedbackSize;
};
```

From `modes.cpp`:

```
void CFB_ModePolicy::Iterate(byte *output, const byte *input, CipherDir dir, size_t iterationCount)
{
    assert(m_cipher->IsForwardTransformation());    // CFB mode needs the "encrypt" direction of the underlying block cipher, even to decrypt
    assert(m_feedbackSize == BlockSize());

    unsigned int s = BlockSize();
    if (dir == ENCRYPTION)
    {
        m_cipher->ProcessAndXorBlock(m_register, input, output);
        m_cipher->AdvancedProcessBlocks(output, input+s, output+s, (iterationCount-1)*s, 0);
        memcpy(m_register, output+(iterationCount-1)*s, s);
    }
    else
    {
        memcpy(m_temp, input+(iterationCount-1)*s, s);  // make copy first in case of in-place decryption
        m_cipher->AdvancedProcessBlocks(input, input+s, output+s, (iterationCount-1)*s, BlockTransformation::BT_ReverseDirection);
        m_cipher->ProcessAndXorBlock(m_register, input, output);
        memcpy(m_register, m_temp, s);
    }
}

void CFB_ModePolicy::TransformRegister()
{
    assert(m_cipher->IsForwardTransformation());    // CFB mode needs the "encrypt" direction of the underlying block cipher, even to decrypt
    m_cipher->ProcessBlock(m_register, m_temp);
    unsigned int updateSize = BlockSize()-m_feedbackSize;
    memmove_s(m_register, m_register.size(), m_register+m_feedbackSize, updateSize);
    memcpy_s(m_register+updateSize, m_register.size()-updateSize, m_temp, m_feedbackSize);
}
```

---

> How to ***set*** internal state of a CFB_Mode Encryption Object?

This one is easier. Just call `SetKeyWithIV` or `Resynchronize`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To set the state, do you think I have to call `SetKeyWithIV` with the previously extracted `m_temp` or `m_register` value?