# How to get a key stream block for a specific counter in AES/CTR encryption

Tags: encryption, aes, crypto++

I'm using Crypto++ library

I made the IV and key and passed them to the function

```
    CTR_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
    e.SetKeyWithIV(key, 16, iv);
```

Then when I encrypt I use the transformation filter on the string itself to get the encrypted string.

[image]

I want to get the final cipher key which XORed with the string to encrypt it ?
Is there a way to get it from encryption object ?

Comment: You mean the stream key? Just XOR the ciphertext with the plaintext and there you got it.

Comment: How to get the cipher text from key and iv ?

Comment: Oh, you don't have a plaintext. I see, generate a plaintext that completely consists of 0x00 bytes with the length that you need and encrypt it to get the stream key.

Comment: One of the base classes, [`BlockCipher`](http://www.cryptopp.com/docs/ref/class_block_cipher.html), has a `GetNextIV`. But I don't think its what you are looking for. I think it generates a new IV, and does not provide the next IV used in the cipher's state. See, for example, [How to get/set internal state of a CFB_Mode Encryption Object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28744134)

Comment: @Marteen - I like the title changes, but I'm not sure some of it makes sense. The key is the same before and after encryption. Getting the encrypted CTR block is not helpful because he cannot increment the encrypted block. I believe he wants the CTR block that gets encrypted under the key. But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the key stream that was XORed with the first 16 bytes of plaintext (as the picture suggests) then you need to encrypt a block of 16 bytes set to `00` using the same AES CTR mode. A block of key stream, when XOR'ed with all zero's simply returns the same stream. So you can do this for as many blocks of plaintext that you require. As you already guessed you need to use the same key and IV.

If you want to only decrypt something much further in the stream then you need to calculate a new 16 byte IV. You can do this because the IV is directly used as initial counter (possibly right-padded with zeros). So you just need to calculate how many blocks where pre-processed and then add this value (as big endian value) to the IV. This of course only works for block boundaries, you may need to discard some bytes from the key stream if you want to jump to a very specific offset.

Comment: How to do the 16 bits of 00 values ? the encryptoin methodtakes string not hex values and if i passed "000000000000000" as string it'll be converted to 0x303030303030 in hex representation and will be xored and gives wrong final key ???

Comment: Well, yes, you need `00` byte values. Simply specify them as hexadecimals and decode them before use. Or - this being a C++ question - as `"\x00\x00 (etc)"` or char array like this: `{0, 0, ...}` or `memset` using `0` as value or...

Comment: Thanks a lot.
it turned out that using anyvalue will do the job. I Xored the resulted value after encryption with the same string and I got the key.
as double xor will return the original value

Comment: Yep that works as well, as long as you know the original value in advance.